# Multiple row sorting with some special requirements

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to achieve something for an eCommerce website, the idea is to have the result order by the subcategories, but making sure that all the items from the specific category selected appear first and the items where the secondaryCategories show last.

The catch is that I want to be able to merge all the items with the same subcategory in to the same section; this is in the case of an item where it matches the secondaryCategories but there is also one that matches the specific category these should be together.

A am able to do this generating a Select ..Union All.. Select... dinamically with PHP, but this makes the query slow depending on how many union and select statements are generated.

I would like to see if somebody has a better idea on how to do this the closest I got was this SQL to get the result I want but it still does not put together all subcategory items, and if I put the subcategory first on order by then the items from the specific category that I am looking for don't come up on the top of the list, they get mixed up with the secondaryCategories.

```
    SELECT myFields FROM  items where (category = :category or 
FIND_IN_SET(:category,secondaryCATEGORIES)>0)and moreFilters 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Category= :category THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC,subcategory ASC
```

Sample data:

```
Name           Category          Subcategory       secondaryCategories
Adapter1       Adapters          Audio Adapter     Audio
Adapter2       Adapters          Video Adapter     Video
Adapter3       Network           Network Adapters  Adapters
Adapter4       Audio             Audio Adapter     Adapters
```

After sort is:

```
Name           Category          Subcategory       secondaryCategories
Adapter1       Adapters          Audio Adapter     Audio
Adapter2       Adapters          Video Adapter     Video
Adapter4       Audio             Audio Adapter     Adapters
Adapter3       Network           Network Adapters  Adapters
```

What I want it to be:

```
Name           Category          Subcategory       secondaryCategories
Adapter1       Adapters          Audio Adapter     Audio
Adapter4       Audio             Audio Adapter     Adapters
Adapter2       Adapters          Video Adapter     Video
Adapter3       Network           Network Adapters  Adapters
```

Comment: table structures, sample data and explain output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone was wondering the same, I solved this issue by adding some code in my program.

What I did was first do a select and order on the subcategories, once I got the subcategories in order I used them to generate the SQL query using a loop to generate "when subcategory = {subcategory_from_query[1]} then 1 when subcategory = {subcategory_from_query[2]} then 2 and so on"

If adding the a sample php code helps let me know and I will post it.